# Any problems adding a new SSD to iMac 2011?

Tags: imac, ssd

I have an iMac 2011 mid-model. I bought this without a SSD, now I want to add one.

I heard the model have several problems, when it comes to adding extra SSD's. Including *TRIM* support and *Temperature Sensor*. But I want to add it if those problems are acceptable.

I want to know if there are *any* problems, with adding a SSD, and workarounds for the problems.

Is there any Apple certified SSD that I can purchase now or later? I will bring my iMac to Apple's service center, and let them to add it, to keep AppleCare.

---

Update.

I'm living in Korea. And here is no Apple retail store and Genius bar. So I asked this question here.

Comment: There **aren't** any problems adding an SSD to a Mac. Zero. None. You also don't need to purchase an SSD through Apple, but merely have a qualified technician install it. Call Apple for installation details: 1-800-MY-APPLE or your local Apple Retail Store.

Comment: @cksum Oh I heard that there are some problems when I call Apple's service center...

Comment: Why did I get 2 down votes? Could you explain the reasons?

Comment: I wondered that as well. I think this is because your question was difficult to understand at first. Also, you are asking several questions answered at once. Try to split them up. You live in Korea, huh? (I live in Germany, but my mom is Korean!) While there only few Apple Stores outside of the US, there are many Apple Premium resellers: http://www.apple.com/kr/reseller/index.php

Answer (score 1):

The German IT magazine computerbase has done tests comparing the efficiency of  TRIM and garbage collection in SSDs of 2010.

The result is that **recent SSD have a very effecient garbage collection so that the performace difference to TRIM vanishes**. ([source, German](https://www.computerbase.de/artikel/laufwerke/2010/test-ssds-von-corsair-supertalent-und-intel/7/))

Upgrading the HDD on a Macbook does not void the warrenty ([source](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?artnum=303721)). However, it does on a Macbook Pro (I think). Since replacing the hard drive on an iMac will require lots of tinkering, I'm pretty sure that you will void your warrenty.

Detailed guides as to how you replace your harddrive can be found [here](http://www.ifixit.com/Browse/Mac):
They include pictures, step-by-step guide and info on what kind of screwdrivers you need.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a Genius about replacing hard drives in Macs, and he replied that there is no problem warranty wise as long as it's not an iMac. For this machine only you need a technician to do the work. Has to do with temp sensors.

As a side note, RAM modules in every Mac except the MacBook Air (because they are soldered on the motherboard) can be replaced by the user without voiding the warranty, including the iMac.

Also, unless I am mistaken, if you did not order the iMac with an SSD built-in you cannot put one in later on as it misses the support brackets for a 2.5 in HD, therefore it gets tricky. Perhaps an Apple tech can prove me wrong. This is really odd from Apple, because it must not cost a 100$ to put support in the machine, and it gives options to buyers… Oh well.

Comment: All aftermarket SSDs come with a 2.5" to 3.5 bracket adapter.

Comment: I don't know which brand you might be thinking about specifically, but the ones I use and know about dont have bracket adapters in the box. It is always optional. Besides, I was talking about the reserved spot for a 2.5 SSD/HD in the iMac separate from the 3.5 one. It'd be nice to have both, speed and space in one computer...

Comment: All OCZ drives come with the bracket. So do OWC. So do Corsair. So do Kingston. So do Intel. Either select or all. Plenty of choices available for anyone requiring a drive with a bracket. Consult http://www.newegg.com/Store/Category.aspx?Category=119&name=SSD for more details.

Comment: So why, for example, OWC' site says: "* Desktop machines with 3.5" drive bays require an adapter bracket such as the NewerTech AdaptaDrive." like I said, probably doesnt come in the box, but is available separately, at extra cost. But still, no link with my answer above, which pertained about the specific spot for a 2.5 in HD in the iMac

Comment: And I think it's a lot of waste giving away something that might be needed, kinda stupid. Should be provided when you need it...